# Failed to build project with the pre-configured prod profile

Tags: jhipster

When I execute command *mvnw -Pprod*, i get BUILD FAILURE with this error :

```
>[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
>[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
>[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
>[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.5.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.1.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.4.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@0.5.x"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.7"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.6"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.5.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.3"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.5.1"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.2.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.4"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.1.41"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@~0.2.0"
[ERROR] warning Resolution field "source-map@0.6.1" is incompatible with requested version "source-map@^0.4.2"
[INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[ERROR] warning Pattern ["generator-jhipster@latest"] is trying to unpack in the same destination "/Users/jkll/Library/Caches/Yarn/v1/npm-generator-jhipster-4.14.3-f99f8b1cd590b1fdc2908a43d66249daff8baac0" as pattern ["generator-jhipster@4.14.3","generator-jhipster@>=4.13.3","generator-jhipster@>=4.6.0","generator-jhipster@>=2.27.0","generator-jhipster@>=3.0.0","generator-jhipster@>=4.0.0","generator-jhipster@>2.26.0","generator-jhipster@>=4.10","generator-jhipster@>=2.26.0"]. This could result in a non deterministic behavior, skipping.
[INFO] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[INFO] [5/5] Rebuilding all packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
[INFO] $ webdriver-manager update && node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js
[INFO] webdriver-manager: using local installed version 12.0.6
[INFO] [19:41:12] I/file_manager - creating folder /Users/jkll/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/halfearth/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium
[INFO] [19:41:26] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.23.0.tar.gz
[INFO] [19:41:26] I/update - geckodriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /Users/jkll/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/halfearth/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/geckodriver-v0.23.0
[ERROR] events.js:183
[ERROR]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[ERROR]       ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
[ERROR]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/jkll/eclipse/eclipse-workspace/halfearth/node_modules/request/request.js:813:19)
[ERROR]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
[ERROR]     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
[ERROR]     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:208:7)
[ERROR]     at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:708:34)
[ERROR]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
[ERROR]     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
[ERROR]     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
[ERROR]     at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:407:8)
[ERROR]     at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:18 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-07T19:45:12+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/416M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) on project halfearth: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --force' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

**Environment and Tools**

Operational system: macOS High Sierra(version 10.13.6)

JHipster Version(s): JHipster Generator v4.14.3

java version "1.8.0_162"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

NodeJS: x64 (by running: node -p "process.arch")

node: v10.8.0

npm: 6.2.0

yarn: 1.9.4

**JHipster configuration:**

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.xinjue.halfearth",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.14.3",
    "baseName": "halfearth",
    "packageName": "com.xinjue.halfearth",
    "packageFolder": "com/xinjue/halfearth",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "201bbd1f0bf1b5cf99931cd98e550fbf31fcf45a",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "protractor"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "otherModules": [
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-ionic",
        "version": "3.1.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-db-helper",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-pages",
        "version": "2.0.4"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer",
        "version": "1.2.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-bootstrap-material-design",
        "version": "3.5.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-swagger2markup",
        "version": "1.2.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-primeng-charts",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-entity-snowflake",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-swagger-api-first",
        "version": "1.0.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-leaflet",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-swagger-cli",
        "version": "2.0.5"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-rest-client",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-primeng-entity",
        "version": "1.0.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-entity-audit",
        "version": "3.1.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-enterprise-pom",
        "version": "0.0.7"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-grpc",
        "version": "0.15.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-leafletmap",
        "version": "1.0.5"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-pace",
        "version": "0.1.3"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-spring-social-connectors",
        "version": "0.0.1"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-entity-audit-and-delete",
        "version": "2.2.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-mssql",
        "version": "2.1.2"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-material",
        "version": "0.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-nav-element",
        "version": "1.4.19"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-darktheme",
        "version": "0.0.7"
      },
      {
        "name": "generator-jhipster-basic-auth",
        "version": "1.0.1"
      }
    ],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en",
      "zh-cn"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have checked in different ways but I still have no clue about what is the issue. Could you please guide me on this issue? Thank you.

(I tried to set --max_old_space_size to 2048 or 6000 in package.json and it did not work)

Comment: Just a guess, try changing `webdriver-manager update` to `webdriver-manager update --gecko false` which can be found in the `postinstall` script in your package.json.  The error is happening during the call to webdriver

Comment: @JonRuddell Thank you for the suggestion. But I still got error: 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:yarn (yarn install) on project halfearth: Failed to run task: 'yarn install --force' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)